# HighStock Chart: Extract time based on user selection from the Navigator window

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am trying to use a Highstock chart with the navigator window as a way of filtering some content based on time on a page.

Ideally I would like the user to narrow the navigator to a time of interest and be able to pass the start and end date/time to a button that would filter the page.

Does anyone know how I could extract these dates/times from the chart?

Thanks in advance

Dave

Comment: Check [chart.xAxis.getExtremes()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.getExtremes())

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a highstock Chart and pass over the options as shown in the code exaple. This creates a handler for the `afterSetExtremes` event. As you can see in the code this allows you to extract the min and max Date values as unix-like timestamp. Now you can do whatever you want with these values. It is a good idea to set `scrollbar.liveRedraw` to false, otherwise `afterSetExtremes` would fire permanently while dragging the navigator.

```
$('#chart-main').highcharts('StockChart', {

    ... other options

    xAxis:{
        events: {
            afterSetExtremes:function(event){
                console.log('---- Date from Chart Object after setting Extremes');
                console.log(new Date(event.min));
                console.log(new Date(event.max));
            }
        },
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    scrollbar:{
       liveRedraw: false 
    },
});
```